# Number Theory Library (NTL) on Mac Xcode - c++ - (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64) Linker error - Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group

Tags: c++, xcode, libstdc++, libc++, ntl

I have used "brew install ntl" on mac.

If I use libc++ in Xcode I get the following linking errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_ntl_gcopy(_ntl_gbigint_body*, _ntl_gbigint_body**)", referenced from: NTL::ZZ::operator=(NTL::ZZ&&) in main.o "_ntl_gfree(_ntl_gbigint_body*)", referenced from: NTL::ZZ::Deleter::apply(_ntl_gbigint_body*) in main.o "_ntl_gsadd(_ntl_gbigint_body*, long, _ntl_gbigint_body**)", referenced from: NTL::add(NTL::ZZ&, NTL::ZZ const&, long) in main.o "_ntl_gmul(_ntl_gbigint_body*, _ntl_gbigint_body*, _ntl_gbigint_body**)", referenced from: NTL::mul(NTL::ZZ&, NTL::ZZ const&, NTL::ZZ const&) in main.o "NTL::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, NTL::ZZ const&)", referenced from: _main in main.o "NTL::operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream >&, NTL::ZZ&)", referenced from: _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I switch to libstdc++ as in: [GCC 4.7/4.8 as Xcode's C/C++ Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686249/gcc-4-7-4-8-as-xcodes-c-c-compiler) I get 'type_traits' file not found. The however does solve the other linker errors.

How do I use the NTL library in Xcode otherwise? Do I have to add 'other linker flags', and if so, how and which ones?

NTL version 11.1.0

Comment: Do you *link* with the actual library?

Comment: I just left it on libc++ and linked with the libntl.37.dylib in build phases and it solved the issue!! Thanks!